# Javascript: How to temporarily disable scroll on a div while swiping another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I've tried `overflow:hidden` but it causes a white flash on each event, there doesn't seem to be a solution. So i'm attemping the javascript way

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); };
```

and

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) { return true; }
```

But that doesn't seem to work if your already activly on the scroll..

Any ideas people?
cheers!

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using jQuery, but if you do you could try this:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
   jQuery('.classOrIdOfYourDiv').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
};
```

Ofcourse you should remove it when the block is release.
Maybe you can give an example in Fiddle?

Comment: Not using Jquery as its a mobile phone app using phoegap, i've done what you've post and that does solve the problem but it creates another. That problem being everytime i swipe a menu the whole page will flash for a second because the overflow was changed.